# systemd link templated service file using absolute path

Tags: systemd

Here is a simple templated service file `cat /root/testservice@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=testservice %i

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'somecommand'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I'd like to link & enable this service:

```
[root]# systemctl link /root/testservice@.service 
Failed to execute operation: Unit name testservice@.service is missing the instance name.
```

So I can't link it and enable when using absolute path. But when I copy service file to `/etc/systemd/system/testservice@.service` and enabling it `systemctl enable testservice@{1..5}.service` everything works fine.

Systemd version is 219

```
[root]# systemctl --version
systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

Is it expected behaviour? Is it possible to `link` templated service file via absolute path?

Comment: Providing instance name is meant to add something like {1..5}, but when trying to exec  `systemctl link /root/testservice@{1..5}.service` systemctl of couse saying that `/root/testservice@{1..5}.service` do not exists.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible. I would just put the service file into a path where systemd expects to look for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with version v219.

Here is bugreport https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/661

Works like a charm in v232!